# Jupyter - open files from another partition

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I'm using jupyter and want to open files from D:\ drive.
When opening Jupyter it opens C:\ drive, but all my files are on D:\ (The OS is on C:).
I tried to change the "Start in" folder, and tried to install Jupyter on D, but it didn't work.
I'll be glad for your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open jupyter-notebook from a command line you have to change the home path before opening it: open a commmpand line then change the working folder like this:

```
C:\Users\USER> cd D:
D:\> jupyter-notebook
```

This will change your home folder to `D:` and you will be able to access the files you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Just one thing, if someone else will have this problem, "cd D:" won't change the working dir to D:\ but "D:".

Comment: I beleive that depends on the on terminal/command prompt and operating system